# Infoblox IPAM logging of API calls?

Tags: logging, infoblox

In our network, more and more services are implemented through pods running on K8S clusters. DNS registration on our ipam is done through API calls when such a pod is spun up. However, I can't find any logging of these calls in neither the audit log nor the syslog. Are those API calls being logged at all? Can they be logged?